# Counting conjugacy classes with a subgroup of prime index

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to understand the classical method of counting classes from Burnside's old book (Note E) (also clarified a bit by Vera-Lopez, Conjugacy classes in finite solvable groups, 1984) : $G$ is a finite group with $N\unlhd G$ of index $p$ prime. If $g \in G \setminus N$ and $C_N(n_1),\dotsc,C_N(n_s)$ are classes fixed by the automorphism $\psi:a \mapsto g^{-1}ag$ on $N$, then all these classes are also $G$-classes. The remaining $r(N)-s$ classes form disjoint orbits of size $p$ by the outer automorphism induced by $\psi$. Hence $p$ of them fuse to give $(r(N)-s)/p$ classes. This counts $s + (r(N)-s)/p$ $G$-classes.

Now the remaining $G$-classes come from the cosets $g^jN (1 \leq j \leq p-1)$. There is a $G$-action on these cosets by conjugation inducing the following equation : $u_x |N| = \sum_{m \in N} \theta_x(m) = |S_x|$, where $S_x = \{ (w,n)\in xN \times N: n^{-1}wn = w \}$, $\theta_x(m)$ counts number of $w$ fixed by $m$. Here $u_x$ is supposed to mean number of orbits of $(xN, N)$ which I don't understand. Which action is it referring to?

Comment: Probably belongs on Maths Stackexchange.

Comment: I think some confusion is reasonable: the action is not defined in the article. Let $s'$ be the number of conjugacy classes in $gN$. The result we need is $s' = s$. I think the intended argument is essentially as follows. By Burnside's Counting Lemma for the conjugacy action of $H$ on $gN$, $|H|s' = \sum_{h  \in H} |C_{gN}(h)|$. If $h$ is not in an invariant class then $h$ commutes with no element of $gN$. For $h \in n_1^G \cup \ldots \cup n_s^G$ we have $|C_{gN}(h)| = |C_G(h)|/p$. Therefore the sum is $|n_1^G||C_G(n_1)|/p + \cdots + |n_s^G||C_G(n_s)|/p| = |G|s/p$. This is $|H|s$, as required.

Comment: @Mark : I guess you mean $H$ by $N$.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I seem to have used $H$ and $N$ interchangeably.